# elasticsearch match only date of date field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

Following is the mapping for date field in elasticsearch index

```
persons:{
    "dob":{
    "type": "date",
    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
  }
}
```

Now I want to search all the persons whose birthday is on 5th of any month.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with above solutions help. I made the query this way

```
"script_fields": {
   "isDOBMatch": {
     "script": {
         "lang":"painless",
       "inline": "doc.dob.date.dayOfMonth==params.dob_match_vals",
       "params": {
         "dob_match_vals": [**pass the value which u want to match**]
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

The above query returns true/false value.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that without reindexing! With a reindex of a date in `text` field, you can't search with `range query` against that field anymore. The best practice is to use a painless script `doc['dob'].date.dayOfMonth` Take a look here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-expression.html#_date_field_api